# Firebase returning field of document null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display a String from a document on my flutter app but it returns null, other fields are displayed properly, in the firestore collection the field of the document exists and it is of type 'String',
all the other field are returning their value and being displayed,
even printing the 'description' field in the console is null.

This is how I create the field of 'description'

```
TextFormField(
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLength: 30,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() => description = val);
              },
              validator: (val) {
                if(val.isEmpty){
                  return 'Please Describe your Handly';
                }
                return null;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter Description',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white70.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white70,
                fontSize: 15.0,
              ),
            ), //description
```

The fire base method

```
onPressed: () async {
                if(formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  setState(() => loading = true);
                  await HandlyCallsDatabaseService(uid: (_ath.currentUser
                      .uid + ' time ' + (DateTime
                      .now()
                      .millisecondsSinceEpoch).toString()))
                      .createHandlyCall(HandlyCall(
                    title: title,
                    type: type,
                    description: description,
                    reward: reward,
                    money: money,
                    name: _ath.currentUser.displayName,
                    score: score,
                    user: _ath.currentUser.uid,
                    time: DateTime.now().toString(),
                  ));
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                 } else {
                  print(Error);
                }
                },
```

The CreateHandlyCall service

```
Future createHandlyCall(HandlyCall call) async {
return await handlyCallsCollection.doc(uid).set({
  'title': call.title,
  'type': call.type,
  'description': call.description,
  'reward': call.reward,
  'money': call.money,
  'name': call.name,
  'rating': call.score,
  'user': call.user,
  'time': call.time,
});
}
```

The flutter code where I try to display the string

```
Text(
              'The job: ${handlyCall.description}',
               style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 13,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
             ),
     ),
```

[The Firestore document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlzuP.png)

[The Tile in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RajrM.png)

Comment: How do you retrieve the document from Firebase (handyCall)?

Comment: I have a provider in this page
https://github.com/One2mellow/handly_app/blob/master/lib/pages/home/home.dart

Comment: I didn't find this part of code ```Text(
              'The job: ${handlyCall.description}',
               style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 13,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
             ),
     ),```

Comment: Hi please look in the expansion_tile branch in this file
https://github.com/One2mellow/handly_app/blob/expansion_tile/lib/pages/home/handlyCalls_tile.dart

Answer (score 0):

**Change your comma with this " " instead ' ' in your Text Widget and I didnt understand %100 but description is already saved as String , so you dont need to write in ${} this . Add toString() end of the your object to make sure.**

```
Text(
          "The job: " + handlyCall.description.toString(),
           style: TextStyle(
           fontSize: 13,
           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
         ),
 ),
```

Comment: Iv'e tried it and Flutter doesn't let you write Text widget the way you did it up here...

Comment: so when you change the comma that ı sad , without toString it was not working right ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are passing a null `handlyCall` to the `HandlyCallTile` here:

```
class HandlyCallTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final HandlyCall handlyCall;

  HandlyCallTile({this.handlyCall});
```

Try to verify what you are passing through and verify that before using `handlyCall` it has data

Answer (score 0):

OK so I fixed it, went through my code again and in the services file I left out the description method so it wasn't being mapped to list when I use the method to fetch the data from stream which my stream is listening to list type of handlyCalls the description and time wasn't being recieved

the new code is:

```
 //handly calls from snapshot
List<HandlyCall> _handlyCallListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  return snapshot.docs.map((document) {
    return HandlyCall(
      title: document.data()['title'] ?? '',
      type: document.data()['type'] ?? '',
      reward: document.data()['reward'] ?? null,
      money: document.data()['money'] ?? 0,
      name: document.data()['name'] ?? '',
      score: document.data()['score'] ?? 25,
      user: document.data()['user'] ?? null,
      description: document.data()['description'] ?? 'No description',
      time: document.data()['time'] ?? null,
    );
  }).toList() ;
}


//get userProfile stream
Stream<List<HandlyCall>> get handlyCalls {
  return handlyCallsCollection.snapshots().
  map(_handlyCallListFromSnapshot);
}
```

where as these 2 lines weren't there till now

```
      description: document.data()['description'] ?? 'No description',
      time: document.data()['time'] ?? null,
```